# Personal wiki: changing the names of several pages

Tags: mediawiki

In my wiki I sent in a request to add a new namespace called 'Exchange', however adding the new namespace will delete all pages with the name 'Exchange:blahblah'. So I would need to change the page name for all these pages before requesting to add the namespace. The problem is that there are just under 1000 pages such as 'Exchange:blahblah' and changing the names of all of them would take up too much time.

My question is how, if possible, can I change the names of all these pages without having to manually alter the name individually. That is, if I wanted to change every exchange page from 'Exchange:blahblah' to 'Exchange1:blahblah', then is there a quick and easy way to change them all. All the pages are under the same category, if that helps.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/movepages.py) has a script for that!

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote might be because this is not really a programming question

Answer (score 1):

Add the namespace then run `php maintenance/namespaceDupes.php --fix --move-talk` from shell. See [its documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:NamespaceDupes.php) for details.